# iPhone 5 won't turn on after screen repair

Tags: battery, iphone, screen, power

A couple of months ago, my iPhone 5 started to have lines on the screen. A common thing that some people do to diagnose that problem is to open the phone and disconnect the connectors to the screen, clean them a bit, and then put them back.

I tried to do it, but once the screen was back in place and I replugged the battery (because I unpluged it for safety reasons when I removed the screen), the iPhone wouldn't turn on.

I've tried the same procedure a couple of times but it still won't turn on.

It's been 3 months now. Can anyone help me?

Comment: No one can help you here. You broke something in the phone while trying to fix it.

Comment: Were you been able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a dead thread, but you may have possibly bricked the device. Try to make sure all screws inside are intact and screwed in properly and all cables are plugged in properly. You could have also damaged the battery. If you have another iPhone of the same model you can try swapping out the battery and see if it works in the other phone. If it does not, try replacing the battery. If it does work, try to turn it on and then call it or use find my iPhone or plug it in (just do something that would make noise and make sure the ringer switch is on so it will make noise). If it does not work you may have a damaged logic board and you will probably be better off buying a new phone.